# Kein Yehi Ratzon by Birchas Kohanim

Tags: minhag, blessing, kohen-priest

The Minhag by most Shuls where there is no Birchas Kohanim and the Chazan just says the Birchas Kohanim is to say Kein Yehi Ratzon. Why do we say Kein Yehi Ratzon instead of Amein?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what R'YDK meant in his answer, but am not sure, so will state it separately. *Taame Haminhagim* 117 says in the name of the *Avudraham* (or of *abu Dirham*, supposedly):

> A reason we don't answer "*amen*" when the *chazan* says *birkas kohanim* is that we answer "*amen*" only when we hear from someone blessing. Thus, there are some Jews who answer "*ken y'hi ratzon*" instead of "*amen*".

*Taame Haminhagim* writes in *kuntres acharon* there in the name of the *L'vush* what may be the same answer:

> A reason we don't say "*amen*" is that since the *chazan* says it only in the language of a request, starting with "*elokenu... bar'chenu...*", the language of "*amen*" doesn't follow it, rather "*ken y'hi ratzon*", meaning "we, too, ask of Him *yisbarach* that He do so, and so should be His will *yisbarach*. And that's what we practice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm remembering this from a while back and don't currently have the source.

Amen is used following a Bracha or Tefilla (Various interpretations.  Simply, to confirm your belief in the statement), but not when you're quoting a beracha.  When we substitute "Borcheinu vabracha", we are not stating a bracha- that's the job of the kohanim.  We are *requesting* that Hashem should bless us with those barachos even if there aren't any kohanim to verbalize the brachos.  That would make the pesukim a quote of a beracha and not the beracha itself.

Comment: Then why by Yaale V'Yovo and by Musaf of Rosh Chodesh and by Bentching Rosh Chodesh do we not say Kain Yehi Ratzon?

Comment: Unclear writing on my part.  I'll edit with your question in mind.

Comment: You can still ask why we dont say Amen at the end to the tefilah of Borcheinu.

Comment: Re "why we dont say Amen at the end to the tefilah of Borcheinu", isn't it part of the _b'racha_ of _sim shalom_ (which of course we answer _amen_ to)?

Comment: That could be the logic.  The practice of saying Amen during yaale veyavo and Rosh Chodesh Mussaf in the middle of the bracha doesn't mandate doing it everywhere.

Comment: @msh210 Interesting suggestion. Do you have source that they are part of the same bracha?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no: and after reading this your request I looked around a bit, and the _g'mara_ (_M'gila_ 18:1) weakly, and _Rambam_ (_T'fila_ 14:4) strongly, imply the **opposite**. Thanks for questioning it!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (no source) that we want to differentiate between the actual blessing and the Chazzan's substitute for it, so that no one will think that the Chazzan is invested with the ability to do the true blessing.

Answer (score -2):

When a Cohen Rabbi imparts the blessing, the congregation responds "Amen"; but when a non Cohen Rabbi imparts the blessing, the congregation responds "Ken Y'hi Ratzon" (So, it may be His Will.) Please, notice that there are 3 blessings. So, there are 3 answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya William. This doesn't seem to add much to what the questioner originally asked, so perhaps consider [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/61344/edit) it, or turning it into a comment. To learn more about answering questions, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/answering), Or consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to learn more. Fore general help, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).